# How to make the Material UI's table header sticky in relation to an outer scroll?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a page that uses Material UI's table and I need to get the sticky header working when the entire page is scrolled, since the table must be allowed to take as much vertical space as it needs, like in [this pure HTML+CSS](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-jfxmk9?file=/styles.css) example.

I couldn't manage to do this with MUI's table, though. How can it be achieved?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dream-ok8r2q?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Answer (score 8):

Set `overflowX`  to `initial` on TableContainer

```
...
          <TableContainer style={{ overflowX: "initial" }}>
...
```

Read more on [this link](https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/)

Comment: I tried this, but it has the adverse effect of making the contents of the table leak horizontally. When I tried to add `overflow: scroll` to the outer container, it stopped working again.

Comment: @Asghwor you can remove `overflow: "auto" `  from Paper.

Comment: I can't, since I need the table to not overflow from the outer container as well.

Comment: This works but screws up the horizontal scroll of the table when you resize the window to mobile width.

Answer (score 1):

Related issue

---

Wanted mui table with `sticky header` & `rotated to -45 degree angle`

---

**Below din't work:**

Wasted 3 hours to make `stickyHeader` work

```
  <Table stickyHeader ...
```

---

**Below worked:**

1. Apply `head1` CSS for `TableHead`:
2. Apply `rotatedContent1` CSS for `TableCell's child` (NOTE: child):

Full code is something like below:

```
const TableStyles = theme => ({
  head1: {
    zIndex: 3,
    position: 'sticky',
    top: '0px',
  },
  rotatedContent1: {
    transform: 'rotate(270deg)',
  }
})

const Component1 = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <Table>
      <TableHead className={classes.head1}>
        <TableCell>
          <div className={classes.rotatedContent1}> header value </div>
        </TableCell>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
       <TableRow>
        <TableCell> value </TableCell>
       </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
     </Table>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default withStyles(TableStyles)(Component1)
```

Comment: thank you. I was using <TableContainer> as parent of the <Table> and could't make the stickyHeaders work. I remove it and it worked. Incredible.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you can follow these steps:

1. Set overflowX: 'initial' in your TableContainer component's style
2. Add stickyHeader props to your Table component

Here's an example:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ overflowX: 'initial' }}>
  <Table stickyHeader aria-label="customized table" ref={tableRef}>
      {/* ... */}
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

By following these steps, you should achieve the desired result!

Best of luck!